# bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, как узнать программно открыто ли модальное окно Js

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно проверить видимость контейнера

```
$('.bs-my-modal').is(':visible');
```